# Is there any scientific basis behind the "Big Mistake" theory in Hyperion?

Tags: science, hyperion-cantos

The [Big Mistake](http://hyperioncantos.wikia.com/wiki/Big_Mistake) of the Hyperion books says:

> The "Big Mistake" was a cataclysmic event thought to have destroyed Old Earth, having been brought about when a team of physicists in Kiev **created an artificial black hole in a laboratory, which then plunged to the center of the planet and began consuming it from the inside out**

While I know this is science **fiction**, I do wonder if the author Dan Simmons did some scientific research while writing this part, and reached a conclusion such a thing can happen for real? Or is this purely something from his imagination without any real science behind it?

Comment: This is a real world science question, which is off-topic here.

Comment: You might want to Google "Black Hole" and go from there. Black Holes are real things. A Black Hole would indiscriminately consume our entire Solar System. There's a _Supermassive_ Black Hole (Yay, Muse) at the centre of our Galaxy. If a Scientist ever created one capable of sustaining its own mass, it would cause a heck of a lot of problems. But we wouldn't have to worry about those problems, because we'd all be dead and turned into spaghetti.

Comment: Short answer - it'd take something very very heavy to create a black hole that would live long enough to consume Earth. It'd probably be easier, energy-wise, to blow the planet up. [citations needed] (Also, +1 for Muse, @DisturbedNeo)

Comment: As I understand it, the trick with black holes is that they're really dense. You'd need a lot of mass (thousands of tons) to even make it last a few hours, and even then it'll be smaller than an atom. Such a black hole might fall into the Earth, consuming everything it hits, and still not eat enough to sustain itself. See [this answer on Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2743/on-the-immediate-effects-of-a-small-short-term-black-hole/9417#9417).

Comment: Well, was looking for something the author wrote, or someone studying his books.

Comment: @Molag done, thanks.

Comment: It was (after retcon?) fiction even in-universe. Maybe when Simmons found out it's in practice non-sense.

Answer (score 10):

It is most likely conjecture from an incomplete understanding of black holes at the time. Black holes consuming planets is a plot device as far back Larry Niven's "Hole Man" in 1975.

Hawking Radiation, the process by which low mass black holes evaporate, was an early theory by Steven Hawking in 1973, but it hadn't really entered public consciousness by that time.  Up until recently, around 2010 when Empirical evidence of Hawking radiation was believed to be observed, black holes were seen as unstoppable consumers of matter, with no possible escape.  Even the prospect of turning on the Large Hadron Collider, which could presumably create microscopic black holes, became a media sensation about the dangers of creating Earth-consuming black holes.

So is there scientific basis?  No. Was it a reasonable conjecture at the time? Yes.

Comment: For the record, the 2010 "observation" was of a process thought to be *analogous* to Hawking radiation, not actually of Hawking radiation proper.  The popular news tended to blur over (or outright ignore) the difference.